# Reading from text file pwd email

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Right now my code is

```
email = 'test@gmail.com'
pwd = 'testing123'
 
user.send_keys(email)
user.send_keys(pwd)
```

Now I want to read email and pwd from text file instead, this is on the code.

Lets say I have an info.txt in the same folder
I tried with f open but it doesnt work im completely lost

```
 email = 'test@gmail.com'
pwd = 'testing123'
 
msg = 'testy123'
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
 
driver.get('https://www.randomsite.com')
print ("Logging in and doing requests.")
 
user =  driver.find_element_by_id('login_email')
user.send_keys(email)
 
 
password = driver.find_element_by_id('login_password')
password.send_keys(pwd)
```

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: ` email = 'test'
pwd = 'testing123'
 
msg = 'testy123'
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
 
driver.get('https://www.random site /')
print ("Logging in and doing requests.")
 
user =  driver.find_element_by_id('login_email')
user.send_keys(email)
 
 
password = driver.find_element_by_id('login_password')
password.send_keys(pwd)
`

Comment: Please edit your question with code ( not comment)

Comment: Hello, i do not know how to d o that in comment is not working for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could read a file by using `open("info.txt","r")`

then appending the variables of email and pwd. You could use split once you read the file so you can separate the words.

```
f = open("info.txt","r")
x = f.read().split("\n")
f.close()
email = x[0]
passwd = x[1]
print(email,passwd)
```